# Running Quandl in R "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’"

Tags: r, quandl

I am trying to run a simple command in R using the Quandl package. I am getting the following error when I run though:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’
```

The code I am running is:

```
library(Quandl) 
library(xts)
library(zoo)

Quandl.auth("login_token")

mydata = Quandl("FRED/GDP")
```

It is probably something dumb, but I can't seem to find the answer. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to install curl: `install.packages("curl")`

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("curl")
```

I faced the same issue, and saw the comment here [Cannot install devtools package after upgrading R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291690/cannot-install-devtools-package-after-upgrading-r)